# Entity Framework (4.0) how to exclude a related table

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, .net-4.0

I have just updated to using EF 4.0 where before i was using Linq 2 SQL.

I have a query:

```
    var UserList = this.repository.GetUsers();
    return Json(UserList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This was generating an error: "`A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type`"

This prompted this code which worked fine in L2S:

```
  var UserList = this.repository.GetUsers();
      foreach (User u in UserList){
          u.Subscriptions = null;
      }
  return Json(UserList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can i stop EF from looking into the Subscriptions table, i just want the Userlist, none of the related properties and the above example does not seem to work for this.

Cheers,
Kohan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Project your UserList before you pass it to the Json serializer so that it doesn't dive into any of the EF generated properties.

```
var UserList = this.repository.GetUsers().Select(user => new {Name = user.Name, Email = user.Email, ...);
```

Answer (score 3):

There is much more simpler approach for it.
All you have to do is to set **LazyLoadingEnabled** property on your context configuration to **false**

It will be pretty much like the following line:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

And then you can have your query as follow:

```
var userList = from u in context.users
               select u;
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is a much better answer than "projecting" to a dynamic and losing the type advantage.